# Adding TPL extension to Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, opencart

does anyone know how to get my Notepad++ to read tpl files for Opencart. I've already went into settings/style configurations and added the .tpl extension to html and PHP, none of them work.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 6):

Step 1) Run Notepad++ as Administrator.

Step 2) from notepad++ toolbar choose "Settings"->"Style Configurator".

Step 3) Find PHP as a Language from the options on left hand selection box.

Step 4) Add the .tpl extension name into the "User ext" column (just type "tpl" in the user ext box.)

now if you open your .tpl file you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If tpl files have format of HTML, just add tpl to extension-list of HTML type. U did it. If tpl files have other syntax, you need to install tpl-support XML schema for Notepad++. You need to donwnload it first from NP++ custom langs webpage. see how to do it in NP++ help file.